# Please suggest, which is the best method to implemenet in-app purchase(consumable/non-consumable)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I want to implement in-app purchase in my application. There will be more than hundred products and each product will be of fixed rate. All the product details won’t be entered in apple site. There will be one single product and I will be reusing the same for all.  Kindly suggest me the best method that I can use (consumable/non-consumable)?

Comment: Depends on your product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of product are you selling?, depending on it you will have the answer to your question, here are some considerations:

- If you define the IAP as a non-consumable the user will only perform one buy, the next time you try to sell him a product with the same id Apple will return you that this product has been already purchased.
- If you define a non-consumable product as consumable (for example a file that the user can download) your app will be probably rejected.
- If as consequence of the last point if you have to sell a non-consumable product you will have to add each one to iTunes Connect individually.

You do not give us enough information, but taking into account what **I** get from your question I think you will have to create non-consumables.